# Divide two numbers in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my full code:

```
declare @total_csr as int
declare @total_Transaction as int
declare @Avg_days_Open as decimal(18,8)
Declare @Avg_transaction_Per_CSR as int

SELECT @total_csr = COUNT(*)  FROM [APMRS_RG2].[dbo].pdmmast  p where Plan_Num in ('510' ) and 
MONTH(p.Statdate) = @month and YEAR(p.statdate) = @Year

---- Total Transactions  --------
SELECT @total_Transaction = SUM(cast(transaction_count as int)) FROM [APMRS_RG2].[dbo].pdmmast  p where Plan_Num in ('510' ) and 
MONTH(p.Statdate) = @month and YEAR(p.statdate) = @Year

---- AVG Transaction Per CSR
select @Avg_transaction_Per_CSR = CAST(@total_Transaction as decimal(18,8)) / CAST(@total_csr as decimal(18,8))
```

I am always getting the @Avg_transaction_Per_CSR is 0.

Ex: @@total_Transaction  = 5
    @Total_CSR = 26

Comment: well, what data type is `@opendays`?

Comment: Type of open days?

Comment: what are you not telling us

Comment: @Avg_transaction_Per_CSR is int, so how should it show decimals?

Comment: *sigh* `@Avg_transaction_Per_CSR` is an `INT`. You could've save us a lot of time by posting your code the first time

Comment: Sorry guys yes your right. will make sure next time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the type of @opendays

```
Declare @opendays as decimal(18,8))
```

Comment: This is most likely the case. I suspect `@opendays` is `INT` in his code. BTW you have an extra `)`

Comment: Yes I have @opendays as Decimal(18,8) it self. but still getting 0.

Comment: is `@total_Transaction = 0`?

Comment: @user300485 then please post your whole code, what's the point in making us ask you every detail?

Comment: @scsimon: I do not see any extra bracket in my code..script running good.

Comment: Total_Transaction count is 5 and total_Work is 25.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all variables as `decimal(10,22)`.

```
declare @total_csr as decimal(10,2)
declare @total_Transaction as decimal(10,2)
declare @Avg_days_Open as decimal decimal(10,2)
declare @Avg_transaction_Per_CSR as decimal(10,2)
```

Comment: Please review this for typos and improved formatting ( https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ).

Comment: Also please add an explanation how this works and why it is supposed to help. Code-only answers unappreciatedly spread the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Comment: This is how the sql engine treats data.In any database management tool,the division operation behaves normally.